# Why isn't SO using a more MVC-like URL syntax?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

This is not to criticize the current system - it works very well.

But I was just wondering if there were any specific technical reasons why SO is using the URL something like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest
```

instead of the "more" MVC-like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/page/2/newest
```

or something like that?

I ask because I'm tasked with retro-fitting those MVC-style SEO-friendly URL's onto an existing Webforms app, and I was wondering about the motivation of the SO design team for going this route.

Comment: This could be because unlike tags and questions (which *do* have "MVC" style paths) these are options for the same view. Maybe it's not desirable to treat those like "real" URLs from a SEO point of view, for example - but this is just me guessing

Comment: Semantics: Isn't that more aking to "RESTful URLs" as opposed to "MVC URLs"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you read the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)? It's almost surprisingly useful reading for questions like these. Certainly, if I had your task assigned to me, I'd re-read it before I started.

Per the RFC, the `path` is for hierarchical navigation (enabling, e.g., relative links). It is intended to *identify the resource.* The `query` is intended to be *interpreted by the resource.*

Based on this, I would say that SO's URI (which, essentially, says that SO's list of questions is the resource I want, but would you please filter it down to page 2 of the newest ones) is more correct than the URI which says that I want a particular resource called new questions page 2. In particular, I think the `query` is almost always the right place for *optional* filters, especially if there are many of them.

Comment: I have not, as a matter of fact - thanks for the link. This is all pretty new stuff to me so I'm glad for any hints and pointers - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, questions/2 is the URL for *question number 2*. Essentially there are two different axes here... there's the "adding parameters for how we're looking at the list of questions" axis and "navigating *through* the list of questions" axis.

Arguably those might be better off with two different URLs to start with... but I'm not sure. It feels to me like the "navigational" model works better for URL path segments, but the "how we're looking at it" feels okay with parameters.

To think of it a different way, if we were using XML I'd consider the "page=2" and "sort=newest" as natural *attributes*, whereas "question 2" (and then "an answer to question 3") would be natural *elements*. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This describes pretty well what I think too. In addition, when submitting form values via GET, the resulting URL will be in the `&param=value` form too, so this may be a long-term architectural decision.